# Android Studio Plugin to know number of code lines written in a day

Tags: android-studio, plugins

Is there any plugin in Android Studio which can tell me how many lines of code I have written in a DAY (across all the projects). Or maybe some third-party analytics tools

I want to know how much code I write daily for my performance

Comment: Install GIT and init it into your IDE, editor. You can easily track your daily session on GIT and check how many lines you added and removed from your project using the `git diff` command.